# Passing options to UglifyJS2 when using Assetic Bundle

Tags: symfony, assetic, uglifyjs2

As title, is there any way of passing options to UglifyJS2 when using Assetic? Specifically I need to pass the `--comments` option.

I have tried to add the option to the bin setting in my config.yml: `bin: "%uglifyjs_bin_path% --comments"`, but that won't run as it tries to include --comments in the path:

> [Assetic\Exception\FilterException]
>   An error occurred while running:
>   '/usr/bin/nodejs' '/usr/local/bin/uglifyjs --comments' '-o'
>   '/tmp/assetic_     uglifyjs2_outyYVBye'
>   '/tmp/assetic_uglifyjs2_ind932Xh'                         Error
>   Output:
>   module.js:328
>
> throw err;
>   Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/bin/uglifyjs --comments'
>
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
>   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
>   at startup (node.js:136:18)
>   at node.js:966:3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging in the Assetic bundle's source code I found the configuration for the UglifyJS2 filter, [UglifyJS2 Configuration](https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle/blob/master/Resources/config/filters/uglifyjs2.xml). Thanks to that I was able to figure out that to enable the comments option I simply need to pass it along with the bin option, like so:

```
uglifyjs2:
        # the path to the uglifyjs executable
        bin: "%uglifyjs_bin_path%"
        comments: true
```

Edit: Additionally, if you want to pass arguments to a given option you just pass the argument to the wanted option and the option itself will be added automatically. I am for example running comments with a custom regex:

```
uglifyjs2:
        # the path to the uglifyjs executable
        bin: "%uglifyjs_bin_path%"
        comments: /^\/*\**!/
        compress: true
        mangle: true
```